# object that was saved with commit=False, still saved

Tags: python, django

I have a very big model, with steps form. So I decided on each page get previous object and update his attributes in form. In first form I do:

```
def save(self, commit=False):
        obj = super(FirstForm, self).save(commit=False)
        obj.id = 999999999
        self.request.session['obj'] = pickle.dumps(obj)
        self.request.session.save()
        return obj
```

Id is required by mtm. So I set default one.

Then on last step in view I do:

```
obj = self.request.session.get('obj')
obj = pickle.loads(obj)
obj.id = None # remove temporary id
obj.save()
```

But Django save two objects. One normal object and one empty with id 999999999 . Why ?

I tried do:

```
obj = super(FirstForm, self).save(commit=False)

obj.id = 999999999
self.request.session['obj'] = pickle.dumps(obj)
self.request.session.save()
obj.delete()
```

But it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This likely happens because the `id` field is used as a primary key for your model. When you set `id` to `None`, and then save the object, it'll actually create a new object with an id that's iterated sequentially from the previous last object.

Comment: do you have any solution, how to avoid this ?